# Chrome and Safari ignoring (?) position:absolute

Tags: html, css, webkit

Have a look at http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/

In Firefox and even Internet Explorer (!!!) the pop-up menus appear perfectly, vertically centered in the white strip, and always starting on the far-left-hand-side.

In Chrome, the menus start horizontally under the parent `li`, and are not centered vertically. I can fix the vertical alignment by targetting webkit with a different  position, but I can't fix the horizontal alignment.

Why is Webkit ignoring `position:absolute;left:0;`?

CSS:

```
#header #menu
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#header #menu ul
{
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 margin-top:28px;
 height:24px;
}

#header #menu ul li
{
 display:inline;
 position:relative;
}

#header #menu ul li a
{
 display:block;
 float:left;
 padding:7px;
 padding-bottom:3px;
 background:#fff;
 margin-right:5px;
 text-decoration:none;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 font-family:'museo', serif;
 font-size:12px;
 text-transform:uppercase;
 color:#fff;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding-left:12px;
 padding-right:12px;
 background:#01973D;
 position:relative;
 z-index:2;
}

#header #menu ul li:hover a
{
 background:#00BB4A;
}

#header #menu ul li ul
{
 clear:both;
 display:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:39px;
 width:700px;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

#header #menu ul li ul li
{
 display:block;
}

#header #menu ul li ul li a
{
 background:#fff !important;
 color:#000;
 font-weight:normal;
 padding:7px;
 padding-left:11px;
 color:#01973D;
 padding-top:10px;
 margin:0;
 float:left;
}

#header #menu ul li ul li a:hover
{
 color:#000;
}

#header #menu ul li:hover ul
{
 display:block;
}
```

HTML (CMS-generated):

```
<div id="menu">
 <ul>
  <li class="parent"><a class="parent" href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/about-us/"><span>About Us</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/about-us/"><span>Company History</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/about-us/meet-the-team/"><span>Meet The Team</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a class="menuactive parent" href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/portfolio/"><span>Portfolio</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/portfolio/"><span>View before, during and after photos from recent projects</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parent"><a class="parent" href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/"><span>Services</span></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/design/"><span>Design</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/patios/"><span>Patios</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/decking/"><span>Decking</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/turf/"><span>Turf</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/ponds/"><span>Ponds</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/driveways/"><span>Driveways</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/fencing/"><span>Fencing</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/electrics/"><span>Electrics</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/services/garden-structures/"><span>Structures</span></a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 // etc
</div>
```

Comment: Correct URL http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/ - without s at the end.

Comment: Whoops, an extra S!
http://www.habitatlandscape.co.uk/

Comment: First guess `#header #menu ul li ul` missing `left` or `right` property.

Comment: @David adding `left:0` places the submenu to the right of the main menu in Firefox, and changes nothing in Webkit - the Chrome problem still exists, but breaks it in Firefox too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've created a mess by `display:inline`-ing your `<li>` elements but `display:block`-ing your `<a>` elements.

In HTML, it's invalid to nest a block-level element in an inline element:

```
<span><div>FAIL</div></span>
```

When you do something like this, you're going to have cross-browser problems. The same goes if you use CSS to change the `display` property:

```
<div style="diplay:inline"><span style="display:block">STILL A FAIL</span></div>
```

Which is what you've done:

```
#header #menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    /* ... */
}
#header #menu ul li a {
    display:block;
    /* ... */
}
```

That behavior is more or less undefined as far as the specs are concerned (since it makes no sense) so the browser reserves the right to do something insane or ridiculous - which is what you're seeing. It works in Firefox only because you're getting lucky and it works in Internet Explorer because Internet Explorer is inherently insane and ridiculous.

If you want those `<li>` elements to stack horizontally, `float:left` them instead of inlining them. Then you can `display:block` your `<a>` element without issue. Once that's done you'll still have to switch up which elements are `position:relative;`-ed, and probably add a `left:0` somewhere.

[Here's an example of your current issue on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cuq5M/), and [here's an example of my suggested fix on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Cuq5M/2/), which involves positioning the `#header #menu ul` element relatively instead of the `#header #menu ul li`.

Comment: Whoops! I had a little mistake in the second jsfiddle. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

When I gave the `#header #menu ul li` a `display:inline-block;` it fixed it. It also changed the result of the hidden ul's `top` positioning, which should be 24px to match the height if the button anyways, right?